# Elastic - Grok patterns parses string field incorrectly

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack, grok, data-ingestion

So I have my log message field parsed as separate fields via ingest pipeline and grok processor, but one of these field ( string ) is parsed in format of seperate new log. Better explain it with specific example.
This is my log:

```
{"@timestamp":"2021-08-27T10:53:04.669661+02:00","@version":1,"host":"fafca1a6b0d9","message":"Loose white designer T-Shirt,L,29,1,sylius,1","type":"sylius","channel":"app","level":"INFO","monolog_level":200}
```

This is my simple ingest pipeline:

```
[
  {
    "grok": {
      "field": "message",
      "patterns": [
        "%{DATA:product-name},%{DATA:product-variant},%{NUMBER:current-stock:float},%{NUMBER:order-quantity:float},%{USERNAME:identity},%{NUMBER:authenticated:float}"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "remove": {
      "field": "message"
    }
  }
]
```

Problem is with product-name field. This field value get parse instead of 'Loose white designer T-Shirt' like this:

```
{"@Timestamp":"2021-08-27t11:40:28.159124+02:00","@version":1,"host":"fafca1a6b0d9","message":"Loose white designer T-Shirt
```

It is like the original log format, that is cut in half. What could be wrong? I tested it on Grok debuger with the same message and Grok pattern and this field has been separated correctly,

Answer (score 0):

I want to share my solution for this. Not sure why, but It gets parsed correctly if I put delimeter on a the beginning and end of message and change pattern accordingly. I have put semicolon on beginning and the end.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.